# XtraPivotControl dataarea string?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, devexpress, dataprovider

How can I display string or text data into dataarea in XtraPivotcontrol devexpress, because as I can see there is only numeric,currency etc. datatype support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **data area** ina pivot-grid is normally used for summing up something or do some **calculations**, not for texts.

I think the only way is to **override** the [PivotGridControl.CustomCellDisplayText Event](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraPivotGridPivotGridControl_CustomCellDisplayTexttopic)

Hope this helps...